# Double bitwise NOT (~~) in C#

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I've been reading through `ThreadLocal<T>` implementation and don't quite understand the rationale behind inverting an int id before storing it in a private int filed (`m_idComplement`) and then inverting it back again in almost every expression it's used in. Except for [this case](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/double-bitwise-not/) applicable to JavaScript, I can't find any information on why would double negation be useful in C#?

On line 240 it does assign 0 without negation, but it could've just assigned a -1 and just drop all the other unnecessary ones, no?

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/65419748/ThreadLocal.cs

https://i.stack.imgur.com/drJc5.png

[image]

Comment: @SonerGönül I know. We're talking about ints, there are no destructors here, just bits.

Comment: Perhaps to make it be initialized to a "pretend -1" when it's being auto-initialized to 0. (but then why not just initialize it to -1? I really don't know, but this was the thing I could come up with)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/ThreadLocal.cs) for `ThreadLocal.cs` contains the following comment against this field:

> Slot ID of this ThreadLocal<> instance. We store a bitwise complement of the ID (that is ~ID), which allows us to distinguish between the case when ID is 0 and an incompletely initialized object, either due to a thread abort in the constructor, or possibly due to a memory model issue in user code.

They're essentially switching the default, uninitialized value of the ID from 0, which it would be if stored directly as an `int` field, to -1.

Comment: Thanks! So, it this pattern like a thread-abort-safe version of initializing it to -1 in the constructor and, I assume, slightly better performance than `int?`? It seems to me that likelihood of forgetting to reverse  `~` somewhere is high enough to make nullable a better choice in this situation, or it is not thread-safe?

Comment: @IlyaKozhevnikov Since they're worried about a thread abort in the constructor, maybe they were also worried that `int?` might have the same problem i.e. an abort could happen between setting `HasValue` to true and setting the value itself? Or it might just be a performance thing; they do call the class "lightweight".

Comment: Just noticed they already using the empty-try-finally trick in the screenshot, could've used it in the constructor as well and simply initialized to -1...