# convert javascript double bitwise not to c#

Tags: javascript, c#, double, bit-manipulation

How to convert a double value with double bitwise not in c#.
I have method javascript use double bitwise

```
var i= 0.0008590;
var j= 0.000002;
~~(i / j) * j
console.log(i );
/*
i=0.0008579999999999999
*/
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Double bitwise NOT (~~) in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24428513/double-bitwise-not-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @cwharris I don't think so, the title is promising but the contents of that QA are unrelated to this question

Answer (score 1):

The double complement in JavaScript is a trick to convert a value to a 32bit integer, with fractional values being truncated (not ceiling or floor, but rounded towards zero). C# has an explicit syntax for such a conversion: `(int)value`.

```
var i = 0.0008590;
var j = 0.000002;
var result = (int)(i / j) * j;
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

The result is approximately 0.000858

Or you could leave out the type conversion aspect and merely truncate:

```
var i = 0.0008590;
var j = 0.000002;
var result = Math.Truncate(i / j) * j;
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

An advantage is that it does not have funny behaviour for inputs that result in `i / j` being outside of the range of an integer.